# Fastest way to learn Zend Framework?

Tags: php, security, model-view-controller, zend-framework

If you already have a website design in mind and want to just use Zend Framework's modules (mainly the one's for **security** and **performance**) how would you go about **learning Zend for rapid web development**?

Comment: Have you seen the [Quick Start Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.html) on the Zend Framework website?

Comment: fast way doesn't exists. it'll slow and full of pain and suffering. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html

Sample code, an example starter project, lots of documentation; the Zend Framework manual is one of my constantly open browser tabs.

Comment: The above link shows "page not found" error. Please visit [Zend Framework Tutorials](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/).

Answer (score 6):

For starting refer link:

http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/

and download and read Pdf.

Fastest way is up to you how much time to give to learning and depends on your learning capability.
But am  sure above link will give u a good initiation.

Read ZF manuals and get start with sprite that it's very easy. :)

It's manual itself is good resource for learning. and I can be your guide :)