# Learn Zend Framework 1

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, zend-framework-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest way to learn Zend Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436219/fastest-way-to-learn-zend-framework)

I'm looking to apply to work for a company over my winter break.  They apparently rely heavily on latest of zend framework 1.  For me to get the position, they suggested I create a project using the zend framework.  I was thinking something along the lines of a simple blog.

Does anyone have any suggestions for learning the zend framework 1?  Whenever I search, I find information on zend framework 2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436219/fastest-way-to-learn-zend-framework

Answer (score 3):

Here is a really good, and free, online book/tutorial by [Pádraic Brady](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/) about Zend Framework 1, and best practices in using it: [SurviveTheDeepend](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/).

Pádraic is a core contributor of ZF1 (and 2), and creator of Zend_Feed_Reader/Writer and writes a lot about security in PHP applications. His blog is definitely worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

[ZendCast](http://www.zendcasts.com/) is a fantastic resource to learn ZF1.